# extend org-tags-view to show body of the matching node

Tags: org-mode, org-tags, org-roam

In my org files I have many entries that hold a tag. I use them (among many other things) to create reading lists and such. The `org-tags-view` then shows these items in a list and I browse through them. I would like to extend the list with the body of the node (this generally is a single paragraph with some notes on the subject.

I came to this idea based on a video by Tiago Forte and Anne-Laure Le Cunff that discuss her workflow https://youtu.be/gXYj8UNmy48?t=193. She uses tags in Roam Research and then queries the tags to create a content overview list.

I have not found a way to extend the `org-tags-view` to do what I want, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps `org-agenda-entry-text-mode` can accomplish what the O.P. seeks:  https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Commands.html

Comment: Another possibility is to turn on `follow` mode with `F`: the entries are shown in a different window.

Comment: @lawlist that is exactly what I wanted! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was the use of `org-agenda-entry-text-mode`, it shows some lines of text from the node in the tag overview when using `org-agenda`'s tag search.

As an example see the below figure. Within `org-agenda` a search for the tag *emacs* yields 3 entries. Enable `org-agenda-entry-text-mode` to display the entries with the first paragraph of text shown.

[image: org-tag-view with node text]

Comment: Please elaborate. Perhaps show an example.